# jQuery nth element with custom markup

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/3sNbV/

```
$('.box:nth-child(5n)').addClass('edge');
```

.. the nth element is incorrect if you have any other html elements in there besides the one its looking for, although I've specifically given a classname.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour without changing the markup?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$('.box:nth-of-type(5n)').addClass('edge');
```